# Why doesn't my code return the checksum I am expecting and I pre-calculated?

Tags: c, checksum

My program reads a file, calculates a 4 byte checksum by processing the file as four byte integers and summing each chunk, and then compares it to a pre-calculated checksum to check the file's validity.

For example, hello_world.txt could contains the following.

> hello world

I have pre-calculated the checksum, and I know it is 0x49f247db, but the comparison at the end fails.

What could be the issue here? Is it the way I am obtaining the 4 byte integers?

I tried to do this by casting the buffer's pointer into an integer pointer and just iterating over the buffer with the '++' operator but it'd somehow end up skipping bytes.

This is the code I am using.

```
    #include <sys/stat.h> 
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main() {
         unsigned char  buffer [1024];
         unsigned long int        checksum = 0;
         FILE                       *fp;
         int                         i;
         unsigned long int        length;

         fp = open ("hello_world.txt", 0, 0);

         if (fp == NULL) exit(0);

         for (;;)
           {
             memset (buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
             /* Read the next chunk of the file */
             length = read (fp, &buffer, 1024); 
             if (length == 0)
               break;

             printf("i'm here. %d %s \n", length, strerror(errno));
             /* We've read a chunk of the file -- all chunks (except the last)
              * will be '1024' bytes in length; the last chunk will 
              * probably be less than '1024' bytes.
              */
             for (i=0; i<length; i+=4)
               {
                 unsigned long int a = (unsigned long int) ((unsigned char)(buffer[i]) << 24 |
                          (unsigned char)(buffer[i+1]) << 16 |
                          (unsigned char)(buffer[i+2]) << 8 |
                          (unsigned char)(buffer[i+3]));
                 checksum += a; 
               }
           }

         printf("%d, %x \n", checksum, checksum);
         if (0x49f247db == checksum) printf("CHECKSUM MATCHED");
         /* Close the file and return the checksum */
         close (fp);
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: Magic can happen. No, actually it cannot. Where is your code?

Comment: `a=10; b = 16; printf("%u %x\n", a,b);`  - at least they print the same.

Comment: It might be because the two numbers are actually different.  It might be because you printed them using an improper technique (`%d`, perhaps) that inadvertently made them look the same.  It might be because something changed them between the time you printed them, and compared them.  Why don't you show us your code, so we don't have to guess wildly?

Comment: Original post updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined my checksum variable as unsigned long int because that was typedefed as a uint4 in the library I am porting (where the basis for this code comes from). Turns out that the library was only used on 32 bit architectures, so an unsigned long int is 4 bytes whereas on my machine (64 bit) it's 8 bytes. Changing the variable to an unsigned int fixed everything, but I need to do a lot of work porting the library from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Also I should've used %lx instead of %x.